# Can FullCalendar timegridweek view display extra hours after 12am?

Tags: fullcalendar

Does anyone know if FullCalendar's timegrid view has the ability to shift the time window that is displayed?  I.e. On Monday, showing 5am (Mon) - 5am (Tues) instead of the standard 12am-12am.

A working example of this (not sure what calendar library is used tho) can be found on [the shovel app](https://shovelapp.io).

Comment: I don't think timeGrid can do this (as each vertical column is always encapsulated within a regular day), but the Timeline can.